# Class too large exception in a large Ballerina project while bal build

Tags: ballerina

I am generating a Ballerina Project with 250+ Ballerina files and each `.bal` file has at least 2 `const`  defined with in.

However, when the generated project is tried to build, it throws the following exception.

```
[2022-11-23 15:37:08,733] SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - Class too large: wso2healthcare/healthcare$0046fhir$0046r4/0/constants/$_string_constants 
org.objectweb.asm.ClassTooLargeException: Class too large: wso2healthcare/healthcare$0046fhir$0046r4/0/constants/$_string_constants
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:538)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.bir.codegen.split.constants.JvmBStringConstantsGen.generateConstantInit(JvmBStringConstantsGen.java:130)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.bir.codegen.split.JvmConstantsGen.generateConstants(JvmConstantsGen.java:91)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.bir.codegen.JvmPackageGen.generate(JvmPackageGen.java:809)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.bir.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.java:96)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.bir.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.java:71)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.performCodeGen(JBallerinaBackend.java:309)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleContext.generateCodeInternal(ModuleContext.java:473)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleCompilationState$4.generatePlatformSpecificCode(ModuleCompilationState.java:132)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleContext.generatePlatformSpecificCode(ModuleContext.java:381)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.performCodeGen(JBallerinaBackend.java:165)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.<init>(JBallerinaBackend.java:134)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.lambda$from$0(JBallerinaBackend.java:112)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageCompilation.getCompilerBackend(PackageCompilation.java:169)
        at io.ballerina.projects.JBallerinaBackend.from(JBallerinaBackend.java:111)
        at io.ballerina.cli.task.CompileTask.execute(CompileTask.java:130)
        at io.ballerina.cli.TaskExecutor.executeTasks(TaskExecutor.java:40)
        at io.ballerina.cli.cmd.BuildCommand.execute(BuildCommand.java:252)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
        at io.ballerina.cli.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

As to check whether the issue persists with reduced number of `.bal` files in the project, I have tried reducing `.bal` files around to 50 and then `bal build` completed successfully.

Any valuable insights on what causes this exception while building for the whole project and any remedies, are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the compiler. Could you please report this [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%2FBug%2Ctriage&template=type_bug.yml&title=%5BBug%5D%3A%20)

Looks like your code have many string constants, I think any hard corded string literal is placed in `constants/$_string_constants`.
I feel the way around this is to move some string constants and string literals from current module to separate module or to loading them at the runtime.

First try to create a separate module and move some of the string constants/literals into that.

If it doesn't work we can also try to load those string value at runtime.
Maybe use ballerina [configurable](https://ballerina.io/learn/configure-ballerina-programs/configure-a-sample-ballerina-service/) facilities.
configurable

Comment: Thank you, @Dhananjaya for the information and workarounds. I will try them out. For your reference, the issue is reported at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/38796